# CouchDB SSL fatal decode error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, couchdb, ssl-certificate

I'm running CouchDB 1.6.1 on Windows 64bit server 2012 R2, usually we use nginx to manage the SSL however this time I've attempted using CouchDB directly.
Our SSL is a GlobalSign organizational SSL and I have the cert, private key and intermediate cert from the provider. I have setup my local.ini as follow:

```
[daemons]
; enable SSL support by uncommenting the following line and supply the PEM's below.
; the default ssl port CouchDB listens on is 6984
httpsd = {couch_httpd, start_link, [https]}

[ssl]
cert_file = ../ssl/organizational.crt
key_file = ../ssl/privatekeyfile.key
; set to true to validate peer certificates
;verify_ssl_certificates = false
; Path to file containing PEM encoded CA certificates (trusted
; certificates used for verifying a peer certificate). May be omitted if
; you do not want to verify the peer.
cacert_file = ../ssl/intermediate.crt
```

When I check via curl I get the following output:

```
curl -k -v https://companyURL.com:6984
* Rebuilt URL to: https://companyURL.com:6984/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying IP.IP.IP.IP...
* Connected to companyURL.com (IP.IP.IP.IP) port 6984 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=GB; ST=LONDON; L=LONDON; OU=IT; O=COMPANY;CN=*.edge10hosted.org
*        start date: 2015-03-27 14:18:04 GMT
*        expire date: 2018-05-03 11:17:17 GMT
*        issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.39.0
> Host: companyURL.com:6984
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: CouchDB/1.6.1 (Erlang OTP/R16B02)
< Date: Tue, 31 Mar 2015 13:00:39 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 151
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
<
{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"34155abcacbffc53e67a224f5f1ea7c7","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"version":"1.6.1","name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}
* Connection #0 to host companyURL.com left intact
```

And running https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html checks out fine.

CouchDB logs show

```
SSL: certify: tls_connection.erl:2286:Fatal error: decode error
```

Any thoughts as to what the issue could be as the certificates work fine elsewhere and via nginx.

Comment: You ever find the solution to this?

Comment: It was an issue with the version of CouchDb and using an organizational SSL cert and intermediate cert. We ended up using the proxy to handle the ssl traffic.